# How to wrap a C++ library

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm developing an application which is using a library and I would like to wrap this library so that it does not goes to deep into my application code. Thanks to that I could change the library I'm using just by re-implementing my wrapper classes.

Suppose that I have a library LibA. It gives me 2 objects to work with, LibAObj1 and LibAObj2. LibAObj2 has a method using LibAObj1.

Here can be a simple definition of their declaration

```cpp
class LibAObj1 {};

class LibAObj2 
{
     void action(LibAObj1 &obj);
};
```

Now I would like to define an interface that my application can use to wrap those objects in my application code

For instance:

```cpp
class ItfLibAObj1 {};

class ItfLibAObj2 
{
public:
     void action(ItfLibAObj1 &obj) = 0;
};
```

The problem comes whenever I want to implement my interface ItfLibAObj2.

```cpp
class ImplLibAObj2 : public ItfLibAObj2
{
public:
    void action(ItfLibAObj1 &itfObj)
    {
        <how to get my LibAObj1 from itfObj>?
        obj.action(LibAObj1);
    }
private:
    LibObj2 obj;       
}
```

The question is actually in the pseudo code. How to get my LibAObj1 contained in my ItfLibAObj1 reference? I could add a getter function in LibAObj1 interface to return a void pointer that I would cast but I don't find that elegant in C++.

Is there any kind of design pattern I could use to solve my problem? Or do I just have a design issue?

Note that I'm not wishing to select which library to use at run time.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You problem perfectly explains why in Proxy Pattern, both the Real and Proxy must implement the same interface:

[image: UML diagram of Proxy Pattern (source: Wikipedia)]

And your code should look like this:

```cpp
// interfaces
class ItfLibAObj1 {};

class ItfLibAObj2 
{
public:
     void action(ItfLibAObj1 &obj) = 0;
};

// real

class RealLibAObj1 : public ItfLibAObj1 {};

class RealLibAObj2 : public ItfLibAObj2
{
     void action(ItfLibAObj1 &obj)
     {
         ...
     }
};

// proxy
class ProxyLibAObj1 : public ItfLibAObj1
{
private:
    RealLibAObj1 real;
};

class ProxyLibAObj2 : public ItfLibAObj2
{
private:
    RealLibAObj2 real;

     void action(ItfLibAObj1 &obj)
     {
         // do something
         real.action(obj); // delegate to the real
         // do something
     }
};
```

However, if the whole purpose of your "wrapping" is adding a new layer between your core/real and the outside (client), please consider the [Facade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) which provides a simpler interface to the client, instead of merely mimic the classes/methods of the core.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I don't think the Proxy Pattern that you have described is working here. Problem is that inside the action method of RealLibAObj2,  don't have access to the actual object (LibObj1) contained in ItfLibAOj1. So I'm not able to do the following call: libObj2.action(libObj1). Any other though to fix my problem? Thanks!

Comment: the ItfLibAObj1 passed into the `action` method is actually the LibObj1, nothing is contained, and you can directly invoke method on it.

Comment: Hi, my problem is still the same. In my case, RealLibObj2 contains a private member LibAObj1 (which I cannot modify since this is coming from the library I'm using), and I need to make a call such as: libAObj2.action(libAObj1). In this example, LibObj1 is not passed as a parameter of action (ItfLibAObj1 is passed instead), but contained inside the ItfLibAObj1 I'm passing. Any other thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about my code or your code? In my code, the `RealLibAObj2` is actually the `LibAObj2` in your code :)

Comment: I understand better your point now. I was talking in my code. I cannot modify `LibAObj2` since it is coming from a library I'm using. So in my case `RealLibAObj2` cannot be `LibAObj2`. Eventually, I need access to my `LibAObj2`